# Two submit buttons (one hidden and one visible)

Tags: javascript, php

One button is hidden so if it reaches the setTimeout, It will submit the page. The other button is visible and gives them a message that " You are about to close this attempt.

These are the two buttons:

```
<input type="submit" style="display: none;" name="autosubmit" onclick="autoclick()">
<input type="submit" value="Submit and finish" onclick="return changeSncro()">
```

There is the javescript:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    setTimeout(function() {
    document.querySelector('[name="autosubmit"]').click();
}, (5000));

function autosubmit(){
sncro = 0;
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var sncro = 0;

function changeSncro(){
sncro = 1;
return confirm('You are about to close this attempt. Once you close the attempt you will no longer be able to change your answers.')

}


window.onbeforeunload = function (evt) {
    if(sncro !=1){
        var message = 'If you leave prior to SUBMITTING your test, it WILL NOT be scored and you WILL NOT get another attempt';
        if (typeof evt == 'undefined') {
            evt = window.event;
        }
        if (evt ) {
        evt.returnValue = message;
        }
            return message;
    }
}

function maximize(){
    window.moveTo(0, 0);
    window.resizeTo(screen.width, screen.height);
}
maximize();
</script>
```

Right now the Time out works, but it's submitting it like someone hit the X button in the browser. It needs to just submit the information. The visible button is working like it should.

Thanks

Comment: Since the onclick function is set on this, wouldn't it just make more sense to run `autoclick()` directly in the setTimeout function?

Answer (score 0):

It's a submit button so it will submit the form. Try a) using a plain button, b) stopping the default behaviour of your submit button, or c) not using a button at all. You've got a timer running, why not make it just do the thing you want with a function call?

BTW this code looks like something from 1998. It's technically correct but I suggest you look into a modern library like jQuery and learn about event listeners. If you're relying on some online resources for learning this stuff, look around for others. A lot has changed in 15 years and seeing "onclick" in HTML should be a big red flag! Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I figured out why it didn't work. Calling the wrong function on the onClick for the hidden button.